# NPE with reflection

Tags: java, reflection, nullpointerexception

I am trying to run a client and access fields to set/get values.  As the script starts, I create a new instance of the client class loaded with `URLClassLoader` and assign it to `gameApplet`.

Now, the next piece of code works fine (Accessing a static field):

```
Class<?> clientClass = clientClassLoader.loadClass("client");
fps = clientClass.getDeclaredField("fpsOn");
fps.setAccessible(true);
fps.set(null, true);
```

But then, when I try to access a non static field:

```
logged = clientClass.getField("loggedIn");
logged.set(gameApplet, true);
```

I get this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeBooleanFieldAccessorImpl.set(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Unknown Source)
    at launch.run(launch.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm assuming it's the instance that is null, but why would it then get a static field?

Comment: Please don't start sentences with 'OK' or 'So'.  If you remove those inane terms, the sentence makes every bit as much sense.

Answer (score 4):

You don't seem to be creating 'instance' of the class. You need to invoke the constructor of the class and then use the instance where required.

Above code works for static fields as they are accessible from class i.e they don't require an instance.

Comment: How should this be done? I think I'm doing it right, I just didnt show this:

Comment: gameApplet = (Applet) clientClass.newInstance();

Comment: @user1204813 The exception will come when you call set(null, true). So may be you are assigning gameApplet after calling set?